# Excel conditional formatting with CountIf

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, countif

If got a long spreadsheet I'm maintaining for my job. I need to add a highlight rule to a single column, that will highlight any cell which is duplicated within the column more than X times. So, a rough example, the following list of values in column B:

```
a
b
a
c
d
a
e
f
a
b
```

would highlight all the "a" cells if I set the count to >3.

Now, I'm currently using conditional formatting, applied only to column B, and tried these two variations in the formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$1000,$B2)>10
=COUNTIF($B:$B,$B2)>10
```

Straightforward enough, right? Except, it's missing cells it should highlight, and highlighting cells it ought not.

Can anyone point me where to go to troubleshoot this? I've no idea what I've buggered up...

Thanks!

**EDIT: The answer is: make sure your formula range and the range you apply the CF to match up! Also that your referent matches the first cell in the range. I was trying to use a formula that started in B2 but the affected range was B:B. Bad combo. My second example was using B:B in both the formula and the range, but was using B2 as its referent. Thanks Scott for helping me out!**

Comment: What is the range that you are applying the CF to?

Comment: the `$B2` should refer to the upper cell in the applies to range.  So if you are applying it to the full column it should be `$B1`.

Comment: The CF is applied to `B:B`. Ah, maybe that's it.

Comment: Yep, that's it. The CF was not applied to the same range being referenced within the formula. Thanks Scott!